# PHP 7.1 Docker build will not compile with pgsql

Tags: docker, php-7.1

I am using the polinux/httpd:centos repo to run Apache and PHP 7.1.  The build seems to go ok.  There are a few warnings related to keys, but none related to php or pgsql.  The build completes successfully, but when I ssh into the container the module is not listed (php -m) and there's no extension config file in php.d.

I verified it is listed in the Dockerfile multiple times. 
I can install php71-php-pgsql manually after starting the container, but then I can't restart Apache without restarting the container.

I've tried moving `yum install php71-php-pgsql` to the end of the Dockerfile as a separate RUN command (in addition to the original), but it reports it has already been installed, yet when I ssh into the container its not listed in the modules and no config, as mentioned above.

When I rebuild a container I stop and remove it, then run build with the no-cache option.

I'm stumped...

The Dockerfile is quite long, but I can post if that would be helpful.

Thanks.

UPDATE: Dockerfile per request...

```
FROM polinux/httpd:centos

ENV \
    NVM_DIR="/usr/local/nvm" \
    NODE_VERSION="9.2.0" \
    GIT_VERSION="2.15.0" \
    PHP_VERSION="71"

ADD mariadb.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/mariadb.repo

RUN \
  rpm --rebuilddb && yum clean all && rm -rf /var/cache/yum && \
  yum update -y && \
  yum install -y \
  wget \
  patch \
  bzip2 \
  unzip \
  make \
  openssh-clients \
  git \
  MariaDB-client && \
  rpm -Uvh http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm && \
  yum install -y \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-bcmath \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-cli \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-common \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-devel \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-fpm \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-gd \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-gmp \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-intl \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-json \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-mbstring \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-mcrypt \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-mysqlnd \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-pgsql \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-opcache \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-pdo \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-pear \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-process \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-pspell \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-xml \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-pecl-imagick \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-pecl-mysql \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-pecl-uploadprogress \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-pecl-uuid \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-pecl-memcache \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-pecl-memcached \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-pecl-redis \
  php${PHP_VERSION}-php-pecl-zip && \
  ln -sfF /opt/remi/php${PHP_VERSION}/enable /etc/profile.d/php${PHP_VERSION}-paths.sh && \
  ln -sfF /opt/remi/php${PHP_VERSION}/root/usr/bin/{pear,pecl,phar,php,php-cgi,php-config,phpize} /usr/local/bin/. && \
  mv -f /etc/opt/remi/php${PHP_VERSION}/php.ini /etc/php.ini && ln -s /etc/php.ini /etc/opt/remi/php${PHP_VERSION}/php.ini && \
  rm -rf /etc/php.d && mv /etc/opt/remi/php${PHP_VERSION}/php.d /etc/. && ln -s /etc/php.d /etc/opt/remi/php${PHP_VERSION}/php.d && \
  yum install -y \
    ImageMagick \
    GraphicsMagick \
    gcc \
    gcc-c++ \
    libffi-devel \
    libpng-devel \
    zlib-devel && \
  yum install -y ruby ruby-devel && \
  echo 'gem: --no-document' > /etc/gemrc && \
  gem update --system && \
  gem install bundler && \
  export PROFILE=/etc/profile.d/nvm.sh && touch $PROFILE && \
  curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.2/install.sh | bash && \
  source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && \
  nvm install $NODE_VERSION && \
  nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION && \
  nvm use default && \
  npm install -g \
  gulp \
    grunt-cli \
    bower \
    browser-sync && \
  echo -e "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config && \
  curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer && \
  chown apache /usr/local/bin/composer && composer --version && \
  yum clean all && rm -rf /tmp/yum* && \
  sed -i 's|SetHandler application/x-httpd-php|SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"|g' /etc/httpd/conf.d/php${PHP_VERSION}-php.conf

ADD container-files /

ENV \
  NODE_PATH=$NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules \
  PATH=$NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

RUN \
  mkdir -p /data/tmp/php && \
  chmod -R 777 /data/tmp

# Weird issue: For some reason pgsql is not installed above.  May be OoO...  
Manually installing worked, so adding here at the end.
RUN \
  yum install php71-php-pgsql -y
```

Comment: Please add your `Dockerfile` to the question.

Comment: It's weird, but your `Dockerfile` works pretty fine without last `RUN` layer  on my ubuntu 16.04 host with docker version `18.03.0-ce`: https://pastebin.com/AEpwenQV

Comment: Thanks Nickolay, When you ssh into the container is php-pgsql installed correctly?  I'm working with Docker version 17.12.0-ce, but why would that matter?

Answer (score 0):

Chalk this up to inexperience...
This turned out to be a problem with how I was referencing images, first when building and then running the instance.  I'm still not sure I fully understand, but I think I was running the base container instead of the modified build.

For others that may run into similar problems, the 2 commands that helped me get this working are:

```
docker build --rm -t local/httpd-php71 .
```

... and then ...

```
docker run \
  -d \
  --name httpd-php71 \
  --restart unless-stopped \
  --net dockersubnet \
  --volume /www:/var/www \
  local/httpd-php71
```

Where 'local/httpd-php71' is my local/custom build.  Before I was not using any tag reference in the build command and then I was referencing 'polinux/httpd:centos', the base, in the run command.

Thanks.